# How to represent multiple relation between two entity sets in ERD?

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

I'm trying to build ERD for an airplane company while study. I made two entity sets, `Flight` and `City`. As you see, `City` could be a destination of `Flight` and an origin of `Flight`.

So I think I need two one-to-one relations,`Destination` and `Origin`, to represent this situation. But I don't know how to represent multiple relations between two entities. Just use two diamond shapes is the answer to this case?

[image: ERD I made]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make only two entities sets at least there will be redundancy in cities table which will conflicts with database normalization rule.

[Refer to database normalization rules](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)

You have to set three entities:

1-Flights

2-Destination_Cities

3-Origin Cities.

Then make your relationship between Flights and the two other entities.